# pmneila Maching cube, configure input

Tags: python, numpy, 3d, marching-cubes

I am working in python and try to use pmneila Maching cube (https://github.com/pmneila/PyMCubes).

In my system, I got a list of coordinates for each of my cubes.
A simple example :

```
myCubes = []
myCubes.append( vec3(x,y,z) )  # for each of my cubes
```

I can't figure out how to convert this to the marching cube input's.

I want something like:

```
u = doStuffToConvertMyCubesListe(myCubes)
mcubes.marching_cubes(u, 0)
```

In the provided example it build a sphere with `numpy.mgrid`, but I can't figure out how.
I tried to build a big cube from little cubes through the marching cube algorithm.

Can you explain how to do that ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out

So, each coordinate [X][Y][Z] is the voxel coordinate.

Positive Value mean this voxel is inside the geometrie (where I previously spawn a cube) and negative value mean it is outise the geometry (where there is nothing)